# Calculate Last Working Day

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to calculate the last working day for a process. Typically, this will be yesterday. However, if the process runs on a Monday it should bring back the date of Friday.

My calculation is:

```
Today()-MakeTimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Current code stage 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Best Practice in this area is to use VBO called "Calendars", that is a Internal one, built in the BluePrism.

```
Object: Calendar
Action: Add working days
Calendar Name: "Working Week / No Holidays"
Date: Today()
Days -1
```

An advantage of that solution is that you can customize the calendar to add all Holidays that are Bank Holidays for your company.

Comment: Thank you for your clarity and helpfulness!

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I've been able to accomplish this by using a dedicated Utilities object with an action that's just a single code stage. The action has a single Output connected to a single output of the Code stage.

```
out = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
While out.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or out.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday
    out = out.AddDays(-1)
End While
```

This also opens the ability for you to add complex logic to account for holidays in your locale(s) without cluttering up your action page.

Comment: In this example, where the common use is that the output should be the previous day, the first line of the code should be `out = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)` otherwise you're starting 3 days earlier - on a Wednesday, you'd return the previous Friday as the last working day.

Comment: @Dave My mistake - forgot to change it after testing my assumption! I’ve edited my answer.

Comment: Good stuff - now I can upvote in clear conscience :)

Comment: Thanks for the above. However, I am a little confused. I have used your code and I am not getting any out put. I have simply connected my code stage to the end stage. Is there another step that's needed? I have attached a screenshot to the question

Comment: Is the `out` variable defined in the code stage's `Outputs` tab and connected to the data item?